# php setcookie doesn't work when posting with JS

Tags: javascript, php

I have a strange problem-
In my website https://www.example.com I have this JS code, triggered on some JS event:

```
$.post( 'https://www.example2.com/api/save_cookie.php',
    { storageData: storageData },
    function(data) {console.log(data)}
);
```

In https://www.exmaple2.com, the file save_cookie.php looks like this:

```
$test = setcookie('test_cookie', '1', time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60), '/');
echo $test;
```

When I trigger the JS event, I can see in the network tab that everything is okay, that the request sent successfully to the url https://www.exmaple2.com/api/save_cookie.php, and I can see "1" printed in the console, from the callback function.

But in https://www.exmaple2.com, `$_COOKIE['test_cookie']`, is `null`.
However, If I just browse the url www.exmaple2.com/api/save_cookie.php, and check the variable `$_COOKIE['test_cookie']` after that, I can see that the value is '1', as expected.
Any ideas why the cookie is not set when posting the request with ajax?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a doubt, can you try to save cookie without path in the end of function setcookie? ( , '/')

Comment: @GabrieleCarbonai still not working..

Comment: it is really wired because it is look like your cookies are not setting globally, but how you write must to be global. Try to add =>  '/', NULL, 0 ); or false instead NULL

Comment: give the complete url, add http or https etc

Comment: Have you tried calling https://www.exmaple2.com/api/save_cookie.php before trying it through ajax in a new session?
$_COOKIE after setcookie does not work in the same request as setcookie is the direction for the browser to set the cookie in client side. When the request goes again with updated cookie to server that time $_COOKIE will have that updated value.

Comment: I tried everything, it doesn't work. If I try to test it with lcoalhost domains, it does work though..